# How to check if image has attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  alist of `img`-tags and some of them has attribute `style="display:none"`
For example:

```
<img src="#">
<img src="#" style="display: none">
<img src="#">
<img src="#" style="display: none">
<img src="#" style="display: none">
<img src="#">
<img src="#" style="display: none">
```

How(using jQuery or javascript) I can get elements which doesn't have attribute `style="display:none"`?

**UPD:** I have selected images that have certain source(`$("img[src='http://certain-source.jpg']")`) but some of them has string `style="display:none"` and now I have to select ones which doesn't include that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if the image is visible :

```
$('img:visible')
```

would be the easiest, checking for that exact attribute is another

```
$('img[style!="display: none"]')
```

filtering based on style is also an option

```
$('img').filter(function() {
    return this.style.display != 'none';
})
```

and probably a hundred other solutions ?

Comment: Maybe, you haven't understood me. I have to select img-tags which doesn't include any other attributes except src=""

Read an updated question

Comment: I did understand you, and a `style="display:none"` makes the element invisible, and jQuery has a `:visible` selector, so you can just use that to select the visible elements.

Answer (score 0):

@adeneo gave a nice answer,

You can try with filter also

```
$("img").filter(function() {
 return $(this).css("display") == "none"});
```